# need help to price a european option using finite difference method

Tags: functions, evaluation

I am writing a function to price European option using backward induction finite difference method. The function is expected to price a European option taking Stock (stock_), age (time_), volatility (vol_), interest rate (int_), contractual expiry (expn_), type of payoff (payoff_),Strike ( strike_), number of asset steps used for evaluation option (nas_). I am expecting function to return price of the option based stock price and age (if option is bought today age is zero). I need help as I am only few weeks into mathematica programming so might be making basic mistakes. My code is as attached. Can anybody opine where I am going wrong. I have posted same question in Wolfram community too. Sorry for repeating

optionprice[strike1_, nas1_, expn1_, vol1_, int_] := 
 Module[{ds, s, dt, dt1, t, nts, fd, delta, gamma, theta},
  ds = 2*strike1/nas1;
  dt = 0.9/(vol1*vol1*nas1* nas1) ;
  nts = IntegerPart [expn1 /dt] + 1;
  dt1 = expn1/nts;
  s = Table[i*ds, {i, 0, nas1 + 1}];
  t = Table [j*dt, {j, 0, nts}];
  fd = ConstantArray[1, {nas1 + 1, nts + 1}];
  fd = ReplacePart[fd, {i_, nts + 1} :> Max[(s[[i]] - strike1), 0]];
  Table[fd[[1, j - 1]] = (1 - int*dt)*fd[[1, j]], {j, nts + 1, 2, -1}];
  Do[
   Do [ If[i == (nas1 + 1), 
     fd[[i, j]] = 2*fd[[i - 1, j]] - fd[[i - 2, j]],
     delta = ( fd[[i + 1, j]] - fd[[i - 1, j]])/(2*ds); 
     gamma = ( fd[[i + 1, j]] - 2*fd[[i, j]] + fd[[i - 1, j]])/(ds*ds);
     theta = - 0.5*vol1*vol1 *s[[i]]*s[[i]]*gamma - 
       int*s[[i]]*delta + int*fd[[i, j]];
     fd [[i, j - 1]] = fd [[i, j]] - theta *dt], 
    {i, 2, nas1 + 1}]
   , {j, nts + 1, 2, -1}];

Export["tests1.xls", fd]
  ]

Regards

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Can you clarify what `d2 = Table [ if [j = nts, max (q*( d1[i, nts] - strike), 0), 1], {i, 0, nas}, {j, 0, nts}];` does?  `d1` is a 1D list from your definition, `d1[i,nts]` does not make sense. And in this line `if (stock = d1[i] && nts1 = d3[j], ( euro = d2 [nas1, nts1]), `, where do `i` and `j` come from?

Comment: All built-in Mathematica functions start with an uppercase letter and use square brackets around their arguments.  Arrays/lists are indexed using double square brackets (`[[...]]`). Boolean test on equality is done with `==` not `=`. I see you using `if ( i=0` violating three syntax rules in one statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but it is too long to post in a comment. I have made some modifications in your code, but due to insufficient information given, I cannot completely correct it (I don't know economics). I will put the code here and possibly make other's work easier.

```
boptval[stock_, time_, vol_, int_, expn_, payoff_, strike_, nas_] := 
Module[{ds, dt, dt2, nts, nts1, nas1, q, d1, d2, d3, delta, gamma, 
theta, euro},
ds = 2*strike/nas;
dt = 0.9/(vol*vol*nas*nas);
nts = IntegerPart[expn/dt] + 1;
dt2 = expn/nts;
nts1 = time/dt2;
nas1 = stock/ds;
d1 = Table[i*ds, {i, 0, nas}];
d3 = Table[j*dt2, {j, 0, nts}];
q = 1;
If[payoff == "p", q = -1];
d2 = Table[
If[j == nts, Max[q*(d1[[i]] - strike), 0], 1], {i, 0, 
 nas}, {j, 0, nts}];
Do[If [i == 0, d2[[i, j - 1]] = (i - int*dt2)*d2[[i, j]]]; 
If[i == nas, d2[[i, j]] = 2*d2[[i - 1, j]] - d2[[i - 2, j]]]; 
 delta = (d2[[i + 1, j]] - d2[[i - 1, j]])/(2*ds); 
 gamma = (d2[[i + 1, j]] - 2*d2[[i, j]] + d2[[i - 1, j]])/(ds*ds); 
 theta = -0.5*vol*vol*d1[[i, j]]*d1[[i, j]]*gamma - 
 int*d1[[i, j]]*delta + int*d2[[i, j]]; 
 d2[[i, j - 1]] = d2[[i, j]] - theta*dt2, {i, 0, nas}, {j, nts, 
0, -1}];
If[MemberQ[stock, d1] && MemberQ[nts1, d3], (euro = d2[[nas1, nts1]]), 
euro = (stock*(d2[[IntegerPart[nas1 + 1], IntegerPart[nts1]]] - 
      d2[[IntegerPart[nas1], IntegerPart[nts1]]])/ds) + (0.5*vol*
   vol*stock*
   stock*(1/
     int)*(d2[[IntegerPart[nas1 + 1], IntegerPart[nts1]]] - 
      2*d2[[IntegerPart[nas1], IntegerPart[nts1]]] + 
      d2[[IntegerPart[nas1 - 1], IntegerPart[nts1]]])/(ds*
      ds)) + ((1/
     int)*(d2[[IntegerPart[nas1], IntegerPart[nts1]]] - 
      d2[[IntegerPart[nas1], IntegerPart[nts1 + 1]]])/dt2)]]
```

Comment: Thanks Felix and Sjoerd for your comments. Its very useful. I will work on it and revert. Regarding economics. I am trying to value a european option at certain stock price and and time after option is struck. So if Stock Price (stock_) is greater than Strike (strike_), there will  be pay out at expiry (expn_). The value of uption any time before expiry can be found out using black scholes formula. Black sholes formula is PDE.

Comment: I am trying to solve PDE using backward induction  finite difference method. Table d2 in the code is designed to store value of option at all the grid points of finite difference grid. Table d1 is used to generate stock price which are used for computation in table d2. Table d3 is used to store time steps.

Comment: European option price is give by euro. euro takes one of the values in table d2 if stock price is exactly same as one of the values in table d1 and timestep is exactly same as one of the values in table d3, otherwise it uses black sholes PDE to generate option price from immediate nodes of table d2.

Comment: I tried to make modifications of the two places with trivial syntax errors, but  the code is nor working because you still have two problems, first, `d2` now is only a 1D list with two brackets; second, your index of `Part` is incorrect, note that in *MMA*, the first element in a list is `[[1]]`, not `[[0]]`, and even correcting this, you still have things like `[[j-1]]`, which could return the head or the elements from right side.

Comment: BTW, if you are solving a PDE, why not use `DSolve` or `NDSolve`?

Comment: I suggest you to take my code and make further modifications, I don't know economics so it would be nice if you describe the algorithm. And make sure you are taking advantage of built-in functions to solve the PDE, not writing your own.

Comment: Thanks Felix. I will try to use DSolve/NDSolve. Probably much simpler to get a price of option using Dsolve. Only reason I am using Table is because i need option prices in differnt values of Stock price and time.  I need to solve PDE using monte carlo also. I then can compare prices paths using Finite difference and Monte Carlo and understand differences in option price. There can be significant difference between price of American barrier option (till now I have only written code for vanilla European) depending path stock price has taken at different time.

Comment: Not sure if all of that can be done using DSolve but will still try. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Felix. I modified your code but not able get price of the option. Can you pl explain your comment " first, d2 now is only a 1D list with two brackets; second, your index of Part is incorrect, note that in MMA, the first element in a list is [[1]], not [[0]], and even correcting this, you still have things like [[j-1]], which could return the head or the elements from right side". I am using [[j-1]] as I am using backward induction finite differnce method which is supposed to solve the grid from right side (that is from expiry). As payoff of the option is know at expiry. What is MMA?

Comment: ignore the first one... but there is problem with your `[[j-1]]`. you are iterating  with the option `{j, nas, 0, -1}` , the output will be `[[nas]]`,`[[nas-1]]`...`[[1]]`,`[[0]]`,`[[-1]]`. never use `[[0]]` unless you want to get a result of `List` for a list.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any way I can stop loop to go below [[0]] please?

Comment: In this case you can simply use `{j, nas, 1, -1}`

Comment: I made changes but when I call function boptval["100", "1", "20", "5", "2", "c", "100", "80"]. It still doesn't return euro or price of option. It is not throwing error too.

Comment: @KausikDatta you shouldn't add double quotes unless it is a string.

Comment: even if I want to execute boptval[100, 1, 0.2, 0.05, 2, "c", 100, 80]...I don't get the option value which is supposed to be euro. Can you pl help where Iam going wrong please

Comment: Hi Felix. I uploaded the new version of code (replaced original code). Now it is calculating finite difference table fd but still some problem in Do Loop where I have two different criteria to update matrix "fd". I am expecting logic in IF which is supposed to work for all element in row (nas1+1) as I start updating matrix from right. However logic is failing after second iteration. Hence matrix is getting incorrectly updated from (10,4)th element. (10,4)th element is computed using previous value of (11,5)th matrix fd (which is 1).Can you opine why Do loop is not updating in correct sequence?